# npm install not installing module devDependecies of a submodule

Tags: node.js, npm

So we have a web application project. Let's call it MainProject. We have other modules that we made. Let's call it ChildProject. The ChildProject's package.json has devDependcies entries.

```
"devDependencies": {
  "some-3rd-party-module": "^1.0.0"
}
```

So I run npm install in MainProject. However, some-3rd-party-module doesn't get installed because when I run npm start, it shows an error. The error looks like this

```
module.js:340
    throw err;
       ^
Error: Cannot find module 'some-3rd-party-module'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:338:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:280:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
```

What are we doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`devDependencies` are the dependencies needed only while developing the module, like testing frameworks. They won't be installed when you're including the module in another project.

If your module ChildProject depends on `some-3rd-party-module` that should be listed under its `dependencies` not `devDependencies`.

Comment: Ah, I'll tell that to my officemate. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Here is an update. I moved the module out of devDependencies into dependencies but it still didn't help. I still got the same error.

Comment: @devwannabe Did you run `npm update` in the Main Project to make sure you have the latest version of Child Project?

Comment: We figured it out. It's dedupping issues on npm binary.

Comment: @devwannabe I'm glad to hear you got it working. Sorry I couldn't help more.